# Parse RSS feeds Externally without any library like google and server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, rss, external

I am trying to impelement a RSS parser which parses feeds using jquery/javascript without calling either google feed api or any server sides. Reason being that i want to implement an auto updating RSS feeds.For that i want it to call RSS feeds and parse from the client itself. With many users using,my server will be overloaded with several requests which i dont want. 
SO what i want is that AJAX should call the feed providers and then javascript should parse the feeds and display it to the user.
Any such plugins or framework is there to achieve it.?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't do cross domain ajax calls so you won't get around a server call to get the feeds

Comment: You may have a look at this for more infos and a simple php proxy to get the feeds from your own server: https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed

Comment: I know, your question was clear.. but there won't be an other solution